# Sorting Dates in a Table By JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, sorting

Ok I do have a javascript code that sort rows by Date in a HTML table.
Now what I did there was to convert the dates to timestamp and sort them by native sort() javascript function but it seems the sorting was not right. what is the problem? is sorting date with timestamp incorrect?

here is what i have done so far

```
var asc = true;

    function sortTable() {
        var tbl = document.getElementById("mytable").tBodies[0];
        var store = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = tbl.rows.length; i < len; i++) {
            var row = tbl.rows[i];
            var rowdatedata = row.cells[1].textContent;
            var rowdatesplit = rowdatedata.split('/');
            var rowdatetimestamp = Math.round(new Date(parseInt(rowdatesplit[0]), parseInt(rowdatesplit[1]) - 1, parseInt(rowdatesplit[2]), 0, 0, 0).getTime() /1000);
            if (!isNaN(rowdatetimestamp)) store.push([rowdatetimestamp, row]);
        }

        if (asc) {
            store.sort(function(x, y) {
                return x[0] - y[0];
            });
            document.getElementById('dateCol').textContent = 'Date ↑';
            asc = false;
        }
        else {
            store.sort(function(x, y) {
                return y[0] - x[0];
            });
            document.getElementById('dateCol').textContent = 'Date ↓';
            asc = true;
        }

        for (var i = 0, len = store.length; i < len; i++) {
            var idno = i + 1;
            store[i][1].cells[0].textContent = idno.toString();
            tbl.appendChild(store[i][1]);
        }
        store = null;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/kCxKn/

NOTE: just click the "Date" header and it will sort

ASCENDING ORDER RESULTS

```
ID  Date ↑  Name
1   2012/08/15  Lerry
2   2012/03/16  Ansley
3   2012/05/18  Robinson
4   2012/10/05  Mp
```

DESCENDING ORDER RESULTS

```
ID  Date ↓  Name
1   2012/10/05  Mp
2   2012/05/18  Robinson
3   2012/03/16  Ansley
4   2012/08/15  Lerry
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, the date format used goes year/day/month. I prefer to format the date as year-month-day to avoid confusion.

Comment: it really not works fine.. it doesn't sort in proper order

Comment: Dates are sorted correctly for me in the jsfiddle you provided. What is the sorting problem?

Comment: i updated the fiddle please look at it again, there is a problem on sorting the months

Comment: Can you add the results of before and after sorting in your question as this could be a locale issue. Still works for me.

Comment: I updated again my post showing the results, it shows the sorting problem

Comment: This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/kCxKn/3/ does not work, but the one you posted in your question does. Can't you just revert?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how `parseInt` works, if the number starts with 0 it treats is as octal number. You have to do `parseInt(value, 10)` to ensure the decimal conversion.