# Use custom sort to sort a html table with time in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I tried tablesorter to sort the time in HH:MM:SS format .But I need a customizable sort to split and sort the time even if the time is varying by minuts or seconds

Comment: Please show what you have tried and provide a [mcve]

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share an example to sort time using hh:mm:ss format .I  looked at the following option of tablesorter https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-date-format.html but it does not format by time.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021789/sorting-time-hhmmss-with-tablesorter-plugin

Answer (score -1):

HTML table sort using Javascript.

HTML :

```
<table class="table-bordered" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="Headers">
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Date start
            </th>
            <th>Date end</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="Entries" data-id="13">
            <td data-field-type="string">1234</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Entries" data-id="24">
            <td data-field-type="string">1352</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">04-10-2012</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">23-10-2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Entries" data-id="8">
            <td data-field-type="string">1124</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">13-05-2014</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Entries" data-id="23">
            <td data-field-type="string">1652</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">07-11-2013</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">22-10-2015</td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="Entries" data-id="23">
            <td data-field-type="string">1652</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">04-12-2013</td>
            <td data-field-type="date">22-10-2015</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript :

```
$('tr.Entries').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this),
             t = this.cells[1].textContent.split('-');
     $this.data('_ts', new Date(t[2], t[1]-1, t[0]).getTime());
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('_ts') > $(b).data('_ts');
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmva17gr/)

Comment: I'm a new bie to the javascript area..it would be helpful if you can guide with an example for this

Comment: There are lot of ways if you are using javascript. Here is the examples sort html table using Date by javascript[http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/kCxKn/]. Referred from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968886/sorting-dates-in-a-table-by-javascript    ...Thanks.